# Using kind of + nouns

Tags: grammar, nouns, countable-nouns

I've been said that in the construct "kind of + noun", if the noun is singular, we should use either "kind of + singular form of the noun" or "kinds of + plural form of the noun".

And if the noun isn't countable we may use either of "kind of" or "kinds of" for it.

Do you agree with that? should we look upon it as a rule please?

Comment: Maybe you can give an example of what you're talking about?

Comment: For example: *What kinds of problems do you have?* Here we can't use "*kind of*" for the plural noun "*problems*", I think.

Comment: For countable nouns, you're correct - but note that you may hear the incorrect "...kind of {_plural_}...". I'd like to see some examples of your thinking with respect to non-countable nouns.

Comment: According to people and other thread's points, my assumption was correct. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

According to the BBC English leaners website and The English-plus University of Toronto site the following rules apply:

1. We use **kind of** if the noun is **uncountable** or a **singular countable** noun.

Ex What kind of coffee is that? **coffee= uncountable**

Ex. What kind of apple are you eating?  **apple= countable/singular**

2. If the noun is plural then we use **kinds of**

Ex. I like all kinds of animals.  **animals = plural**

Another way of saying all of this is that if the **object of the preposition of** is singular or uncountable then us **kind.**

If the **object of the preposition of** is plural use **kinds of**

Also, if we use **quantifiers** like **all, several, some , many** then we always follow them with **kinds of**

Ex. I like all kinds of cars.

Finally, according to most dictionaries **kind of, type of and sort of** all have the same meaning **=type or variety of**

I hope that helps.

Comment: In which direction do they lean? :)